# diameter of a Binary tree recursive approach

Tags: c++, recursion

I am trying to find diameter using recursion  ,I am confused  with recursion

some of the test cases I tried I got correct answer  at some point 
Integer overflow occured But Below author's solution was accepted with same data types

My approach:

For every node, length of longest path which pass it = MaxDepth of its left subtree + MaxDepth of its right subtree.

My question is whats wrong with my implementation

```
  class Solution {
  public:
      int mx = 0;
      int solve(TreeNode* root) {
          if (root == NULL)return 0;
          int leftheight = diameterOfBinaryTree(root->left) + 1;
          int rightheight = diameterOfBinaryTree(root->right) + 1;
          mx = max(mx, leftheight + rightheight);
          return max(leftheight, rightheight);
      }
      int diameterOfBinaryTree(TreeNode* root) {
          solve(root);
          return mx;
      }

  };
```

Authors approach: same approach but different recursion implementation

```
  class Solution {
  public:
      int maxdiadepth = 0;

      int dfs(TreeNode* root) {
          if (root == NULL) return 0;

          int leftdepth = dfs(root->left);
          int rightdepth = dfs(root->right);

          if (leftdepth + rightdepth > maxdiadepth) maxdiadepth = leftdepth + rightdepth;
          return max(leftdepth + 1, rightdepth + 1);
      }

      int diameterOfBinaryTree(TreeNode* root) {
          dfs(root);

          return maxdiadepth;
      }
  };
```

Comment: A question please, you need to put a specific one in your, er, question.

Comment: So what is your question ?

Comment: why my answer getting overflowed

Comment: Where is the `solve` function's implementation?

Comment: The code shown can't possibly compile. It has two overloads of `diameterOfBinaryTree` with the same signature.

Comment: Just changed @IgorTandetnik

Answer (score 0):

Consider the case when you hit a leaf node or the case where you have only one node. Your algorithm returns 2, which is incorrect. This problem arises because you compute the height by adding one to the left / right subtree, no matter what.

To fix this, add one when you return the height, like so: `max(leftheight, rightheight) + 1`

Btw, when you recursively call, you should do `solve(root->left)` or `solve(root->right)` and not `diameterOfBinaryTree(root->left)` :P

Answer (score 0):

In the working implementation, the recursive `dfs` call returns the max depth of the subtree.

In your implementation, the recursive `diameterOfBinaryTree` call returns the currently accumulated approximation to the diameter. You assign it to variables named `leftheight` and `rightheight` - that's misleading; the value is not, in fact, the height of the left or right sub-tree.